# What's the usage of the pubspec's description in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

What's the purpose of the pubspec's description? Is there any way users can see this?

**pubspec.yaml**

```yaml
name: flutter_app
description: A new Flutter project. # Why does it exist?
version: 1.0.0+1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A description is optional for your own personal packages, but it will use when you want to publish your package, which should be in English. Get more details [link](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec#description)

The description will show like this. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; 
This is optional for your own personal packages, but if you intend to publish your package you must provide a description

[From the docs](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec#description) -

> Description This is optional for your own personal packages, but if
>   you intend to publish your package you must provide a description,
>   which should be in English. The description should be relatively
>   short—60 to 180 characters—and tell a casual reader what they might
>   want to know about your package.
>
> Think of the description as the sales pitch for your package. Users
>   see it when they browse for packages. The description is plain text:
>   no markdown or HTML.

Answer (score 1):

This is the usefulness of the `Pubspec's description` according to the official documentation:

> This is optional for your own personal packages, but if you intend to publish your package you must provide a description, which should be in English. The description should be relatively short—60 to 180 characters—and tell a casual reader what they might want to know about your package.
>
> Think of the description as the sales pitch for your package. Users see it when they browse for packages. The description is plain text: no markdown or HTML.

Check for other usages like `name`,`authors`, `documentation` and others in the link provider below:

[Read more about the Pubspec file](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec)